# Move an app on Google Compute Engine to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have an app running on Google Compute Engine. Now it's time, to move this app to Google App Engine.

Is there a checklist on what needs to be done regarding DNS and other configurations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

App Engine is a Platform as a service offering while Compute Engine is Infrastructure as a service. It may not be completely straightforward to lift and shift your app from Compute Engine to App Engine.

It depends on your app's current architecture, programming language etc. Some considerations include:

- Whether your app is stateful or stateless
- whether it uses a database(if so, your method of connecting to the database might change)
- Which programming language and framework your app is using.
- Whether you want to migrate to App Engine Standard Environment(Limited by programming language and framework) or App Engine Flexible environment(Docker images).